# Add Image from onPostExcecute to InfoWindow getInfoContents

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I am retrieving data from my onPostExcecute into an infoWindow. I managed to get the title and the text into the infoWindow but cannot get the image to load inside the same infoWindow. Am I referencing the image correctly? Any help is appreciated. I Commented the lines inside my code where things work and donto work (2 items)

```
            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Item> arrayList) {
            if(isCancelled()) return;
            if(googleMap!=null) {
                googleMap.clear();
                mMarker2Item.clear();
                LatLngBounds.Builder boundBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (Item item : arrayList) {
                    MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(item.location())
                            .title(item.name); // LOAD PERFECT INTO INFOWINDOW
                    if(item.iconBitmap!=null){
                        opts = opts.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.iconBitmap)); // DOES NOT LOAD INSIDE INFO WINDOW
                    }
                    Marker newMarker = googleMap.addMarker(opts);
                    newMarker.setSnippet(item.vicinity);
                    //newMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.iconBitmap));
                    mMarker2Item.put(newMarker, item);
                    boundBuilder.include(item.location());
                }
                try {
                    if (firstTime) {
                        firstTime = false;
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundBuilder.build(), 200);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 1000, null);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            } else mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onPostExecute(arrayList);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }
            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle()); // WORKS GREAT - COMES FROM onPostExcecute marker
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet()); // WORKS GREAT - COMES FROM onPostExcecute marker
                ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageBitmap(WHAT REFERENCE GOES HERE?????); // DOES NOT WORK :(

                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: what do you want to put there? the bitmap of your marker?

Comment: I am looking to place the bitmap which already has access to the image file. But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: the bitmap is in the marker options already, I just want to pass that to my infowindow like I did with the text Title

Comment: is the image draw in your map?

Comment: yes. the image draws in my map, i can click on the image inside the map and the infoWindow appears, but the image or any image is in there. The layout file has an imageView as well

Comment: I want to load that same image inside infoWindow